# What Laurent told Shashi in French while she was sharing her experience in hindi?

Tags: dialogue, english-vinglish

In *English Vinglish*, when Shashi's daughter insulted her on call, she shared it with Laurent in Hindi. Laurent also shared his response in French while he didn't understand her.

What did he really say in French?

Answer (score 5):

From facebook's  [Mehdi Nebbou](https://www.facebook.com/MehdiNebbouFans/photos/a.152477614898190/193774567435161/?type=3&theater)'s fan page:

> When Shashi gets upset with her daughter after phone call, and talks in Hindi with Laurent he says,
>
> "Je comprends pas mais je suis désolé, Shashi"
>
> Which means, " I don't understand but I'm sorry, Shashi.."

<sub>Note: Mehdi Nebbou played Laurent</sub>